# How to split a string with comma separated pairs of colon separated keys and values and pass it into a javascript object?

Tags: javascript, json, replace, split, string-parsing

Currently using str.split(',') on a string and passing it into an array (also simultaneously removing `next lines` and `"` from the string). The string looks like this:

```
let array = [];
const string = "a_key : a_value, b_key: b_value, c_key: c_value";


array = string.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r|\\n)/gm, ' ').replace(/"/g, '').split(',');
```

The results in:

```
console.log(array);

//result:
['a_key : a_value' 'b_key : b_value' 'c_key : c_value']
```

Those values need to be accessed by their key and processed further, it would be better as an object.

Any one see what I'm missing in the regular expression chain?

Summary:

Turn this:

```
"a_key : a_value, b_key: b_value, c_key: c_value"
```

into this:

```
{'a_key' : 'a_value', 'b_key' : 'b_value', 'c_key' : 'c_value'}
```

Comment: Why do you have a string in that format in the first place? It might be better as JSON. Also, if the values happen to be numeric or properly quoted, maybe you could simply insert lead/trail braces and then parse the aggregate string as JSON.

Comment: Are you sure that removing double quotes from the string is a good idea? Also, yes, where is that original structure coming from? edit: like this? https://jsfiddle.net/mtxwy3jv/

Comment: It comes out of an app that only exports to excel. I'm using a node npm script to convert the excel to json, that string is a value (with a key) from a json object.  There were strings with quotes and next lines that broke the script, so that temporary fix was added in a lot of places and probably the quote removal comes out from that spot. Currently I'm looking into passing the array into a loop and splitting each array value with split string again, using : as a separator. Only at the moment, exploring how to rebuild all those strings into an object, maybe there is an easier way?

Comment: Oh, I see, the jsfiddle...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative solution improves the use of regex you made. This could be done by capturing the groups delimited by `:` and `,` maintaining the order of an object. Look:

```js
const string = "a_key : a_value, b_key: b_value, c_key: c_value";
const obj = {}, re = new RegExp('(.*?):(.*?)(?:,|$)','g')

string.replace(re, (_, key, value) => obj[key.trim()] = value.trim())

console.log(obj)
```

How this regex works?

```
  (.*?):  matches anything lazily until colon
  (.*?)(?:,|$)  matches anything lazily until comma or end of string
```

[Here](https://regex101.com/r/9d2Cls/1) if you want to visualize regex in action.

Comment: This bites, by which I mean the regular expressions. However, it's also the selected solution.

Answer (score 0):

The following should get you what you need, but it assumes the values are strings.

```
let myObj = {};

for (let el of array) {
  let key_val = el.split(':');
  myObj[key_val[0].trim()] = key_val[1].trim();
}

console.log(myObj);
```

result:

```
{ a_key: 'a_value', b_key: 'b_value', c_key: 'c_value' }
```

Comment: This result is actually what I'm looking for, but I like the method chaining and anonymous functions in Chris G's answer (his returns a json object, which is what I asked for, but what I really wanted was a javascript object)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [matchAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/matchAll) with 2 capture groups, and map those 2 groups to a multidimensional array, which you can pass to [Object.fromEntries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries).

```
\s*([^:,]+?)\s*:\s*([^,]+)
```

- `\s*` Match optional whitespace chars
- `([^:,]+?)` Capture group 1, match 1+ chars other than `:` or `,` non greedy
- `\s*:\s*` Match `:` between optional whitespace chars
- `([^,]+)` Capture group 2, match 1+ times any char except `,`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/yreABy/1)

```js
const string = "a_key : a_value, b_key: b_value, c_key: c_value";
const regex = /\s*([^:,]+?)\s*:\s*([^,]+)/g;

const res = Object.fromEntries(
  Array.from(string.matchAll(regex), m => [m[1], m[2]])
);

console.log(res);
```